# How to send two reponses to a GCDWebServer request

Tags: ios, gcdwebserver

I'm using `GCDWebServer`'s `addDefaultHandlerForMethod:@"GET"` and sending an NSData response via
     `GCDWebServerDataResponse responseWithData:contentType:@"application/octet-stream"`

The user's browser receives a file which it saves in the Download folder.  So far, so good.  I also want to send a `GCDWebServerDataResponse responseWithHTML:` to show additional information to the user.

Given one GET request, is there a way to send two responses, one with data and one with HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible due to the way HTTP is designed to work: 1 request = 1 response. If you want an HTML page and also a file to be downloaded, return a first response for the HTML page, then from this page itself, using JavaScript or a redirect, now do the download.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, which I'll try out.